# create a collapsable box or window inside a panel in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

I am new to ext.js, and i am working on a project. Where I need a collapsable box for description inside a panel, and there are big number of panels in the window.

Is it possible to create a collapsable or hideable box inside a panel...?
for now I am using tpl to show the description inside a panel.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a `panel` inside a panel with `collapsible: true` property set apart. It displays a `button` on the panel's title which collapses/expands the panel. 
Also you may use `.collapse()` and `.expand()` methods to control it from the code. In this case the title of the panel may be hidden and you'll get the plain box.

Comment: Is it possible to add a panel inside a panel, and show some dynamic data under the collapsable panel....?
I had already 20 panels and all are collapsable and dynamic, and if i add a panel inside a panel, that to collapsable and want to show some dynamic information under the panel. Is that possible..?

Or I was thinking of adding accordion layout inside a panel with a collapsable row and non collapsable row. will that works and solves issue or throw some other issues...?